# An unexpected error has occurred. Web Parts Maintenance Page: If you have permission, you can sue this page to temporarily close Web Parts

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have updated SP2013 farm to SP2016 in a new environment.
Everything went well except some customised web parts. When I click on ex "Create customer" which is a customised webpart I get the error message:

An unexpected error has occurred. Web Parts Maintenance Page: If you have permission, you can sue this page to temporarily close Web Parts or remove personal settings.
I have already deleted and readded the webparts, edited the web.config with different solutions which I found on the Internet but I just got more problems.
I have even deleted and reinstalled the PerformancePoint service application. When I try to add a standard SP webpart, it works fine but not the customised webpart.

Have you please any idea about this issue and how to solve it?

Regards
Ashraf

Answer (score 0):

Are you running the web app in SP2013 compatibility mode? if not the web parts might need to be rebuild for SP2016 (as the SP dll is different)

You can review the Sharepoint ULS logs to check the details of your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a simple redeploy of the webpart will do the trick.

If You manage those .wsp files best approach would be just to open the project created for SP 2013 in VS which has SP 2016 templates installed. VS will automatically prompt you to upgrade the project to target SharePoint 2016. After that just build the project and deploy and check.

Maybe no code correction is needed as SP 2013 and SP 2016 are very similar in many parts.

Please refer to this old [post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/latest-microsoft-office-developer-tools-for-visual-studio-2015/) (the post is from times when SP 2016 was showing up) where at the bottom You have this process described

Comment: Do you mean export the customised webparts from SP2013 and import them into SP2016?
If you mean so then I have already tried to export and import one of them and I got the same issue. But if you mean to redeploy the wsp files I can't because I have n't them.

Comment: unfortunately I meant the second. So having the webpart project (.sln with all other files) and opening it in newer VS and upgrading it. Do You have some dev support person (team, company) that developed this webpart? maybe they could help?

Comment: Now after a big investigation I got information about where to find the original wsp files. But the person is on his annual leav now. When I'll get them I'll redeploy them and give a feedback :). Thank you for your time. 
Regards
Ashraf

Answer (score 0):

You need to manually transfer all customizations to your new farm. Make sure to install any components that your sites depend on to work correctly, such as the following:

Custom site definitions

Custom style sheets, such as cascading style sheets, and images

Custom Web Parts

Custom Web services

Custom features and solutions

Custom assemblies

Web.config changes (such as security)

Reference:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/SharePoint/upgrade-and-update/upgrade-content-databases

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/SharePoint/upgrade-and-update/use-a-trial-upgrade-to-sharepoint-2013-to-find-potential-issues#Customizations

Answer (score 0):

Please try to change below tags in web.config, it will show you the actual error message

1. CallStack="true"
2. CustomErrors mode="Off"
3. debug="true"